# Can't write to .xls with apache poi after checking whether I has same number in it

Tags: java, apache-poi

I created a GUI for user to sign up and I want to make it clear that user havent signed up before.I save all info in a Exel folder that I created with apache poi.It was working good until I add this Property.It doesnt write info to folder whether User signed up before or not.

**and It doesn't throw Exception It works like nothing wrong**

---

```
public void kullaniciGuncelle(String tc, String ad, String soyad, String musteri_no, String telefon, String hesap_turu)throws Exception{


    while (ayniVeriKontrol(tc,musteri_no)){
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("Test.xls");
        isimsiz_banka_verileri = new HSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);

        musteri =isimsiz_banka_verileri.getSheetAt(0);
        sayac = 1 + musteri.getLastRowNum();
        row2 = musteri.createRow(sayac);
        celli = row2.createCell(0);
        celli.setCellValue(tc);
        celli = row2.createCell(1);
        celli.setCellValue(ad);
        celli = row2.createCell(2);
        celli.setCellValue(soyad);
        celli = row2.createCell(3);
        celli.setCellValue(musteri_no);
        celli = row2.createCell(4);
        celli.setCellValue(telefon);
        celli = row2.createCell(5);
        celli.setCellValue(hesap_turu);

        fileInputStream.close();

        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("Test.xls");
        isimsiz_banka_verileri.write(fileOutputStream);
        isimsiz_banka_verileri.close();
        fileOutputStream.close();
    }


}
```

---

```
public boolean ayniVeriKontrol(String tc, String musteri_no) throws Exception{

    boolean kontrol = false;
    String geciciTc ,geciciNo;

    fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("Test.xls");
    isimsiz_banka_verileri = new HSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);
    musteri = isimsiz_banka_verileri.getSheetAt(0);
    sayac = 1 + musteri.getLastRowNum();

    for (int i = 1; i < sayac; i++) {
        row2 = musteri.getRow(i);

        celli = row2.getCell(0);
        geciciTc = celli.getStringCellValue();

        celli = row2.getCell(3);
        geciciNo = celli.getStringCellValue();
        if (geciciTc == tc) {
            System.out.println("Ayılar");
            kontrol = true;
        }
    }

    fileInputStream.close();
    return kontrol;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `It doesnt write info to folder`? Does it throw some exception? If yes, provide the stacktrace

Comment: You should probably stop closing the stream in a loop. Just flush it, don't close until you're done with it

Comment: Your loop is never entered, actually... `geciciTc == tc`.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java and you might want to see [How to debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @cricket_007 Thank you for how to debug.As a student  It can help me to improve my self I changed while fo if else and ıt works now I will Update the post

Comment: @cricket_007 I edited Sorry for bad writing

Comment: @cricket_007 You  can check the answer It works but You may have something to tell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed while loop to if-else condition and now it writes and checks whether file has same user

```
    public void kullaniciGuncelle(String tc, String ad, String soyad, String musteri_no, String telefon, String hesap_turu)throws Exception{


    if (ayniVeriKontrol(tc,musteri_no)){
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("Test.xls");
        isimsiz_banka_verileri = new HSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);

        musteri =isimsiz_banka_verileri.getSheetAt(0);
        sayac = 1 + musteri.getLastRowNum();
        row2 = musteri.createRow(sayac);
        celli = row2.createCell(0);
        celli.setCellValue(tc);
        celli = row2.createCell(1);
        celli.setCellValue(ad);
        celli = row2.createCell(2);
        celli.setCellValue(soyad);
        celli = row2.createCell(3);
        celli.setCellValue(musteri_no);
        celli = row2.createCell(4);
        celli.setCellValue(telefon);
        celli = row2.createCell(5);
        celli.setCellValue(hesap_turu);

        fileInputStream.close();

        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("Test.xls");
        isimsiz_banka_verileri.write(fileOutputStream);
        isimsiz_banka_verileri.close();
        fileOutputStream.close();
    }
    else{
        KayitArayuzu kayit = new KayitArayuzu();
    }


}
```

---

```
public boolean ayniVeriKontrol(String tc, String musteri_no) throws Exception{

    boolean kontrol = true;
    String geciciTc ,geciciNo;

    fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("Test.xls");
    isimsiz_banka_verileri = new HSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);
    musteri = isimsiz_banka_verileri.getSheetAt(0);
    sayac = 1 + musteri.getLastRowNum();

    for (int i = 1; i < sayac; i++) {
        row2 = musteri.getRow(i);

        celli = row2.getCell(0);
        geciciTc = celli.getStringCellValue();

        celli = row2.getCell(3);
        geciciNo = celli.getStringCellValue();
        if (geciciTc.equals(tc)) {
            System.out.println("Ayılar");
            kontrol = false;
        }
    }

    fileInputStream.close();
    return kontrol;
}
```

Comment: This works? In the first block, by closing  `fileInputStream`, I believe you're also closing `isimsiz_banka_verileri` too

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes ıt works.but I open file at the begining of every code blocks

Comment: Why? You could pass it in as a parameter

Comment: @cricket_007 I will try